# Google Charts grid color

Tags: api, colors, google-visualization

How do I change the color of the grid lines for Google Charts API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#gcharts_grid_lines

> This parameter doesn't let you specify
>   the thickness or color of the lines.
>   For more ways to make lines across
>   your chart, see shape markers (chm
>   type h, H, v, or V), range markers
>   (chm), and axis tick marks (chxtc).

Thus you can have a look at what range markers (chm) are:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#gcharts_range_markers

To answer your question, you need to use the chm parameter to draw each line separately. The second parameter defines the color:

```
chm=r,FF0000,0,0.499,0.501
```

The code above draws a horizontal line with color #FF0000 in the middle of the chart.

Comment: Can we use colors from values folder?